# How to retrive the json values (string values display as null and integer 0)

Tags: android, json, retrofit

i'm implement restful client using android.i have API URL,token,etc.i implement this application using retrofit 2 library all are correct.but json values not display properly.
String values display-null
integer values display-0

this is my code.

json string

```
{"user": {"login": 22000,"name": "Test Account - C K (Dev)","native_name":ull,"email": null,"identity": null,"password_last_updated_at": null,"phone": null,"balance": 0}}
```

my Mainactivity

```
 void getRetrofitObject() {

    final String API_BASE_URL = "https://www.example.com/";
    final String credentials = "xxxujfrfkjgrtgkmuhefekmneignkdgrg";
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new okhttp3.Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(okhttp3.Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", credentials)
                            .addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);

                }
            }).addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    LoginA service = retrofit.create(LoginA.class);

    Call <User.UserBean> call = service.getUserDetails();

    call.enqueue(new Callback <User.UserBean>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call <User.UserBean> call, retrofit2.Response <User.UserBean> response) {

            try {



             text_marks_1.setText("User Balance  : " + response.body().getLogin());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call <User.UserBean> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }




    });
}
```

my User class

```
public class User implements Serializable{


/**
 * user : {"login":22000,"name":"Test Account - C K (Dev)","native_name":null,"email":null,"identity":null,"password_last_updated_at":null,"phone":null,"balance":0}
 */

private UserBean user;

public UserBean getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(UserBean user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public static class UserBean {
    /**
     * login : 22000
     * name : Test Account - C K (Dev)
     * native_name : null
     * email : null
     * identity : null
     * password_last_updated_at : null
     * phone : null
     * balance : 0
     */



    private int login;

    private String name;
    private Object native_name;
    private Object email;
    private Object identity;
    private Object password_last_updated_at;
    private Object phone;
    private int balance;

    public int getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(int login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getNative_name() {
        return native_name;
    }

    public void setNative_name(Object native_name) {
        this.native_name = native_name;
    }

    public Object getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Object email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Object getIdentity() {
        return identity;
    }

    public void setIdentity(Object identity) {
        this.identity = identity;
    }

    public Object getPassword_last_updated_at() {
        return password_last_updated_at;
    }

    public void setPassword_last_updated_at(Object password_last_updated_at) {
        this.password_last_updated_at = password_last_updated_at;
    }

    public Object getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Object phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }




}
```

}

and API class

```
public interface LoginA {
@GET("/api/user")
Call <User.UserBean> getUserDetails();}
```

thank you

Comment: Can you remove the initial forward slash in your @GET of the API interface ?

Comment: thank you for you suggestion @rhari but same  thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your API response is

```
{"user": {"login": 22000,"name": "Test Account - C K (Dev)","native_name":ull,"email": null,"identity": null,"password_last_updated_at": null,"phone": null,"balance": 0}}
```

Then the return type for your call should be User and not User.UserBean

Comment: Yes I got it that is the erro thank you @rhari very much

Comment: o sorry for that i'm new for the stack :)